Why does colour work for figure caption number but it does not on table caption number?
I'm compiling a report in R markdown with HTML output using CSS.
The code for the figures works where I can colour the word "Figure" and the figure number which is generated through a function. But the same approach does not work for the table and I can't see why not.
CSS:
/* Custom styles for figure and table captions */

  .figure .caption::before{

  content: "Figure ";

    color: #AA3740; /* Change this to your desired color */

    font-weight: bold;

  }

 

  .figure .caption .fig-number {

  color: #AA3740; /* Same color for the figure number */

  font-weight: bold;

}

 

  .figure .caption span {

  color: #000000; /* Desired color for the rest of the caption */

}

R chunk (where the ref section is used to automatically assign figure numbers):.
```{r figure_1, fig.cap = paste0('<span class="fig-number">',  ref("fig:figure_1"), '</span>: Title’)}```

For the tables I tried similar, but it doesn’t seem to work (I’m using the package flextable):
CSS:
/* Custom styles for figure and table captions */

  .table .caption::before{

  content: "Table ";

    color: #AA3740; /* Change this to your desired color */

    font-weight: bold;

  }

 

  .table .caption .tab-number {

  color: #AA3740; /* Same color for the figure number */

  font-weight: bold;

}

 

  .table .caption span {

  color: #000000; /* Desired color for the rest of the caption */

}

R chunk:
```{r table_1, tab.caption = paste0('<span class="table-number">',  ref("tab:table_1"), '</span>: title’)}```

No caption appears for my table.

you must use the tab.cap option instead of tab.caption, but flextable inserts the caption into a span element, so I could not find any way to insert other html elements and dynamic elements inside

I was not able to get what you want with the flextable package because the caption is already inserted inside a span element so you cannot add other html elements inside (everything is rendered verbatim).
But with a knitr::kable table, you can make it work like this:
```{r table_1, tab.cap = paste0('<span class="tab-number">', ref("tab:table_1"), '</span>: Title')}

knitr::kable(head(iris))
```

and the following CSS:
  .table caption::before{

  content: "Table ";

    color: #AA3740; /* Change this to your desired color */

    font-weight: bold;

  }

 

  .table caption .tab-number {

  color: #AA3740; /* Same color for the figure number */

  font-weight: bold;

}

 

  .table caption {

  color: #000000; /* Desired color for the rest of the caption */

}


